# Why am I getting RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded when mocking datetime.date behaviour?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-import, python-unittest

I am mocking the following function in module `sample.py` following example from the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#partial-mocking):

```
import datetime
from random import randint

def useless_date():
    today_date = datetime.date.today()
    x = randint(0,1000)
    dt = datetime.timedelta(days = x)

    return today_date + dt
```

I have set up a test_file and I notice some odd behaviour in python that I don't understand. The tests run perfectly fine if explicit `date` and `timedelta` imports are used:

```
from unittest import mock
from sample import useless_date
from datetime import date, timedelta

@mock.patch("sample.datetime.date")
@mock.patch("sample.datetime.timedelta")
def test_useless_date(mock_timedelta, mock_date):
    mock_date.today.return_value = date(1999, 1, 1)
    mock_timedelta.return_value = timedelta(days=1)
    mock_date.side_effect = lambda *args, **kwargs: date(*args, **kwargs)

    assert useless_date() == date(1999, 1, 2)
```

However, if I just import the `datetime` module without explicitly importing `date` and `timedelta` I get an recursion error.

Code:

```
from unittest import mock
from sample import useless_date
import datetime

@mock.patch("sample.datetime.date")
@mock.patch("sample.datetime.timedelta")
def test_useless_date(mock_timedelta, mock_date):
    date = datetime.date
    timedelta = datetime.timedelta
    mock_date.today.return_value = date(1999, 1, 1)
    mock_timedelta.return_value = timedelta(days=1)
    mock_date.side_effect = lambda *args, **kwargs: date(*args, **kwargs)

    assert useless_date() == date(1999, 1, 2)
```

Error:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________ test_useless_date ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________

mock_timedelta = <MagicMock name='timedelta' id='4466974048'>, mock_date = <MagicMock name='date' id='4467058096'>

    @mock.patch("sample.datetime.date")
    @mock.patch("sample.datetime.timedelta")
    def test_useless_date(mock_timedelta, mock_date):
        date = datetime.date
        timedelta = datetime.timedelta
        mock_date.today.return_value = date(1999, 1, 1)
        mock_timedelta.return_value = timedelta(days=1)
        mock_date.side_effect = lambda *args, **kwargs: date(*args, **kwargs)
    
>       assert useless_date() == date(1999, 1, 2)

test_sample.py:60: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1081: in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1085: in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1146: in _execute_mock_call
    result = effect(*args, **kwargs)
test_sample.py:58: in <lambda>
    mock_date.side_effect = lambda *args, **kwargs: date(*args, **kwargs)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1081: in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
E   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
!!! Recursion detected (same locals & position)
======================================================================================================= short test summary info ========================================================================================================
FAILED test_sample.py::test_useless_date - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Python version: Python 3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

The recursion in your test occurs because when you write `date = datetime.date` you don't get what you think you get (the original `datetime.date` function), but the mocked function.

As you do `import datetime` in the tested function, the used module is the global module, so writing `@mock.patch("sample.datetime.date")` has the same effect as writing `@mock.patch("datetime.date")` - you are patching the global `datetime.date` function. In your code that means that `date` is the same as `mock_date`, and your side effect is the same as writing

```py
mock_date.side_effect = lambda *args, **kwargs: mock_date(*args, **kwargs)
```

This obviously causes a recursion.

This does not happen, if you use `from datetime import date`, because in this case `date` is a new reference to `datetime.date` living in the module where it was imported. So in your first version, the `date` variable refers to `test_sample.date` (provided `test_sample` is the test module name) and not to `datetime.date`. The same would happen if you had used `from datetime import date` in `sample.py`. In this case you would have to patch `sample.date`, which is not the same as `datetime.date`, and your second test would also work.